# C++ How I can delete temp node mode from memory (to fix leak) and still maintain the node in "keys" list?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Here is my code that has a list of structs. Each struct has id and vector. Essentially I have insert function that adds new node into keys list. Object is created inside the insert when the function is called. Once insertion is finished I want to avoid any leaks
I hope for your help and suggestions!

```
struct Node {
    vector<int> data; //actual int vector
    int id;            //node id
};

list<Node *> keys;

//method{
Node *temp;
if (temp->id != key){
                temp = new Node;
                temp->id = key;
                temp->data.push_back(value);
                keys.push_back(temp);
```

I have troubles in that part of code:

```
                temp = nullptr; 
                delete(temp);   //that's how I'm trying to fix leak.
            }
//}
```

Valgrind:

```
==4199== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4199==     in use at exit: 620 bytes in 20 blocks
==4199==   total heap usage: 82 allocs, 62 frees, 75,452 bytes allocated
==4199== 
==4199== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 4
==4199==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4199==    by 0x10B621: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x10B0EA: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x10AA05: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x10A07D: void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_realloc_insert<int const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x109A91: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x1096F6: key_value_sequences::insert(int, int) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x108F93: main (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199== 
==4199== 36 (32 direct, 4 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 4
==4199==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4199==    by 0x1096C7: key_value_sequences::insert(int, int) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x108F93: main (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199== 
==4199== 296 bytes in 9 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 3 of 4
==4199==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4199==    by 0x10B621: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x10B0EA: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x10AA05: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x10A07D: void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_realloc_insert<int const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x109A91: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x109627: key_value_sequences::insert(int, int) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x108F93: main (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199== 
==4199== 584 (288 direct, 296 indirect) bytes in 9 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==4199==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4199==    by 0x10964F: key_value_sequences::insert(int, int) (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199==    by 0x108F93: main (in /home/admin/CLionProjects/A2/a2)
==4199== 
==4199== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4199==    definitely lost: 320 bytes in 10 blocks
==4199==    indirectly lost: 300 bytes in 10 blocks
==4199==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4199==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4199==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4199== 
==4199== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4199== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: You need to give us enough code to replicate the leak. (But really, you should just use something other than a collection of raw pointers.)

Comment: Seems very likely that your memory leaks are caused by not having a correct destructor for `List`. You should read up on the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). You cannot write a linked list class correctly without understandaing it.

Comment: @john op is likely using std::list.

Comment: You have a list of pointers to objects you allocate with `new`, do you ever `delete` those objects? Even if the operating system free memory when the process exits, it's considered good practice to clean up after yourself before exiting the process. Such clean-up includes freeing memory. Every `new` needs a matching `delete`.

Comment: @n.m. You're right I misread as `list` as `List`. Lack of a destructor to clean up memory is probably still the problem though.

Answer (score 2):

Your `delete temp` does *nothing*, since you're effectively is doing `delete nullptr`.

***But*** you should *not* change the assignment, because after the statement

```
keys.push_back(temp);
```

you have two pointers, both pointing to the very same object.

Then you do

```
delete temp;
```

which destructs that object, making the pointer in the list invalid. Any attempt to dereference the pointer in the list after that point will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In short, you should *not* `delete` the object.

---

If you have a memory leak, then maybe you're not removing and deleting the pointers from the list? Or perhaps it's a false positive and there is no actual leak. It's really impossible to say since you haven't shown any proof of a leak.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that I'm basically deleting both temp and object under temp in keys. I'm still getting "leak_DefinitelyLost" regarding the new Node so I'll have to handle it somehow anyway.

Comment: @opka Then please edit your question to show your leaks. Copy-paste (as text) the full and complete output from your leak-detector. Preferably also try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and show the output from that MCVE.

Comment: I'm using CLion valgrind integration, but I did a check through terminal. Thank you for help!

Comment: @opka When using raw pointers, you need to: (1) create an object with new (2) use that object (3) delete that object. In that order. Please show rhese three steps in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a c++11 compatible compiler you should look at [smartpointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). Otherwise @Some programmers dude is the correct answer.